# Internal Server Error 500 After Memcached Install

Tags: php, python, apache, perl, memcached

After executing the following commands to install and start memcached on a VPS server, I get a 500 internal server error when accessing any files from a web browser:

```
$ yum install memcached php-pecl-memcache perl-Cache-Memcached python-memcached
$ /etc/init.d/memcached start
$ service httpd graceful
```

My apache error log shows the following error every time I attempt to load a file:

```
Premature end of script header: <filename>
```

Something else that I noticed is that I'm still able to run php files from the command line without producing any errors.

Is there something else that I need to do after installing memcached on my server in order to avoid a 500 error?

Comment: there should be something in your http server's error logs that is useful. can you find the relevant logs and post a relevant section?

Comment: @earino My apache error_log file only displays the error "[Sat Feb 22 02:09:12 2014] [error] [client X.X.X.X] Premature end of script headers: in index.php" whenever I attempt to access my website via a web browser. Is there another file that provides more robust error reporting?

Answer (score 1):

That error simply says that the script in your index.php was broken. It did not send any HTTP headers before the error messages. You should check your script and look for an error, which happens before sending http headers.

Comment: I'm glad you asked that because I forgot to mention that after my memcached installation was complete, the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable in all of my php scripts started showing up as empty and causing any require_once calls that used it to fail. After hardcoding the document root in my require_once calls, the php errors went away when running my files from the command line but the 500 internal server error still shows up when I try to access them via a web browser.

Comment: Could you please add your index.php if it is not too long

Comment: I actually found that I get an 500 internal error code when trying to access every file regardless of its contents. For example, if index.php contains just "<?php phpinfo(); ?>", I'll get the proper output by running "$ php /index.php" from the command line but I still get a 500 internal server error when requesting index.php from a web browser.

Comment: Does that "proper output" include HTTP headers, if not it is wrong too. 500 internal server error message is coming from webserver, not from the php engine. So if you are thinking that seeing the content output is enough for you to say it works, you are wrong. All output should include lines such as Content-Type:·text/html; charset=utf-8 or Transfer-Encoding:·chunked etc. Do  you see them?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same problem and no solution found. Then i upgrade apache from WHM panel and everything was reset and start working.

I know it is not a technical solution but it works perfectly.